# Transparent AntiSpam solution in ISP scale

Tags: isp, spam-filter, transparent-proxy

We have and ISP with adsl , broadband etc subscribers (average 10000 online users with 1M of Bandwidth . average ) . Some users infected by spammer viruses which makes our ip address spaces blacklisted in RBLs . I am looking for a **transparent solution without need any change at client side**.

average mail traffic is about 3Mb .

Answer (score 2):

Block outgoing port 25 at your egress, except for traffic to/from your own mailserver, and **business** customers who request it to be unblocked. Then require customers to relay all their mail through it.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the solution . as i said i am looking for transparent solution without need to change client side

Comment: That _is_ the solution, sorry.

Comment: What about something like http://sourceforge.net/projects/assp/ ?

Comment: None of your customers have legitimate port 25 traffic **AT ALL** unless they're businesses running an in-house mail server.

Comment: By the definition of transparent, there can exist no transparent solution that stops your users from sending spam.  However, blocking port 25 except where the user advises you they wish to run a mailserver, like all reputable ISPs do, requires no client-side changes because you can do it at the gateway of demarcation.  There exists absolutely no other correct solution to this problem.